# How can I add an achievement to my resume as a bullet point if the sentence begins with a passive verb?

Tags: resume, standards

I want to write in my resume that I was granted a scholarship after some awards I have got in different competitions. Which bullet point of the following two suggestions is more preferred?

- **Granted** a scholarship after some awards I have got in /something/.
- **Was granted** a scholarship after some awards I have got in /something/.

As I know, we should avoid using passive verbs in resumes. So, in this case, is it OK to use the first form, though it changed the meaning?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is a _good_ question, but not necessarily about the workplace. You'll get more (and maybe better) help over on English

Comment: @BryanH Thanks a lot for your suggestion! However, the answer below is good enough. I don't know if it's possible to migrate this question to another community instead of deleting it, since someone has already answered.

Comment: I'm not positive the question as it's currently written would be on-topic on [english.se]. I'd suggest creating a new question there and rephrasing it to focus on what options you have in the English language and remove the resume context since it's not particularly relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is *rich* with synonyms.  Try "Received".

For a more in-depth answer, "Was Granted" can work, but should follow an active thing that you did that cause you to be granted this thing.

So, something like "Competed in X, Y, Z.  Received a series of awards (enumerate or not).  Was granted Scholarship."  Alternately, "Achieved X in Y Competitions.  Was Granted..."

Don't include false things on your resume.  If you have not granted scholarships, then don't write a resume that might lead people to believe that you were claiming that you had.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggested word, and I will never include false things for sure! OK, so do you think the first form is definitely wrong?

Comment: @Abdulkader I would avoid the first construction.  It is *possible* to misinterpret, and you should always try to make sure that your resume does not have anything open to misinterpretation.  Having someone misinterpret your resume and thereby conclude that you were lying is a good way to get ditched immediately, and even if they do realize what you were saying, the fact that it's not entirely clear will reflect poorly on you.